# bash + mysql syntax problems

Tags: mysql, bash

Where am I wrong? Following is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS=" " read LITRAGE FLOW T1 T2 ;

do echo $LITRAGE $FLOW $T1 $T2;

mysql -u admin-um -pdrums um-jekeha << EOF
use um-jekeha;
INSERT INTO main
(date, litrage, flow, t-hot, t-cold)
VALUES
(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), $LITRAGE, $FLOW, $T1, $T2)
EOF

done < ./log 
exit 0
```

when I run this script on console, I have this message:

```
iam@workstation:~/projecto/um/soft$ sh base1.sh 
11.50 0.70 24.33 25.33 
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-hot, t-cold)
VALUES
)' at line 2URRENT_TIMESTAMP), 11.50, 0.70, 24.33, 25.33
```

11.50, 0.70, 24.33, 25.33 << this is right variables from "log".

What is the problem?

Comment: use sane column names....

Comment: Column name without "-"?

Comment: Thank Karoly!!! Problem is out. ))

Comment: If you are saying the problem is completely solved now, may I suggest posting and accepting an answer?

Answer (score -1):

use sane column names.... – Karoly Horvath

Column name without "-"